# Is it possible to make Java code as groovy style

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to know whether we can write null check pointer in the same statement in Java, as we do in groovy? I've four places to check null. Can this be more simplified?

```
if(doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SEARCH-RESULT-ITEM") != null) {
            if(doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SEARCH-RESULT-ITEM").item(0) != null) {
                Node searchResultNode = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SEARCH-RESULT-ITEM").item(0);
                if(searchResultNode != null) {
                }
           }
    }
```

as

```
doc.getDocumentElement()?.getElementsByTagName("SEARCH-RESULT-ITEM")?.item(0)
```

Is it possible

Answer (score 1):

You asked if it is possible to write Groovy-like code in a regular Java project. The simple answer is no.

However, the statement can be simplified by combining the null checks into one condition. In addition, if `doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SEARCH-RESULT-ITEM").item(0)` is not null we don't need to check the local variable.

So we may end up with:

```
if (doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SEARCH-RESULT-ITEM") != null
        && doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SEARCH-RESULT-ITEM").item(0) != null {
            Node searchResultNode = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SEARCH-RESULT-ITEM").item(0);
}
```

Doing this reduces the number of IF statements from 3 to 1, and eliminates a redundant null check.

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe dereference in Java.

It's generally bad practice to toss nulls around and Optional class may come to rescue as well ass checkNotNull at the beginning of the method, but nothing as fancy as Groovy one-liners.